# How to log in with sudo -i with password in one command?

Tags: sudo

Trying something like `echo 'password' | sudo -iS` doesn't work.

Yes, I'm aware of the security problem. I'm just curious to know how to get something like this to work.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Nothing really. Just trying to learn about how the command is working under the hood. I'm not sure why the command I presented wouldn't work.

Comment: What happened when you tried it, then? It certainly looks correct.

Comment: It prompts for the password by typing "Password:" on stdout. After a couple of seconds it reports "Sorry, try again." Then prints out "Password:\nsudo: 1 incorrect passwod attempt"

Comment: I tried adding \n to end of password but that didn't work.

Comment: Oh, oops. I had the wrong password. It seems to work, however, it dumps me back out to the original user instead of keeping me logged in as root user.